# Иерархический запрос MySQL без начального родительского элемента

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy

**Есть таблица:**

| person_id | employee_id | status | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | WORKER | 3433 |
| 2 | null | WORKER | 3455 |
| 3 | 1 | FRIEND | 2134 |
| 4 | 2 | FRIEND | 5321 |
| 5 | 1 | FRIEND | 3253 |
| 6 | 1 | FRIEND | 5632 |
| 7 | 2 | FRIEND | 3425 |
| 8 | null | WORKER | 3255 |
| 9 | 8 | FRIEND | 3472 |

**Нужно написать запрос, чтобы вывод был примерно таким:**

| person_id | employee_id | status | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | WORKER | 3433 |
| 3 | 1 | FRIEND | 2134 |
| 5 | 1 | FRIEND | 3253 |
| 6 | 1 | FRIEND | 5632 |
| 2 | null | WORKER | 3253 |
| 4 | 2 | FRIEND | 5321 |
| 7 | 2 | FRIEND | 3425 |
| 8 | null | WORKER | 3255 |
| 9 | 8 | FRIEND | 3472 |

Я уже попытался написать рекурсивный запрос, но он выводит не совсем то что нужно. Если есть идеи или предложения, пожалуйста помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY COALESCE(employee_id, person_id), person_id
```

?

Comment: Гениально... Спасибо!

Comment: Только сейчас попробовал поставить person_id больше чем employee_id - правильная иерархия не вышла. Исправил немного и сработало: нужно вместо `person_id` в конце поставить `employee_id`.

Comment: @Rise Неправильная логика. Для такого случая надо ``ORDER BY COALESCE(employee_id, person_id), employee_id IS NOT NULL, person_id``. Но если работает правильно - и фиг бы с ею.